# shorthand for accessor methods in ruby class variables

Tags: ruby

I want some short way and less duplicate way of creating accessor methods for class variables. Here, I see that there is too much same looking code i.e. *methods*. Is there any short way like we have for our instance variables. `@foobar` which will have `attr_accessor :foobar`

```
class User
    @@user_id = 0
    @@user_long = 0
    @@user_lat = 0 

    # User ID

    def self.user_id=(id)
        @@user_id = id
    end

    def self.user_id
        @@user_id
    end

    # Longitude 

    def self.user_long=(longitude)
        @@user_long = longitude
    end

    def self.user_long
        @@user_long
    end

    # Latitude 

    def self.user_lat=(latitude)
        @@user_lat = latitude
    end

    def self.user_lat
        @@user_lat
    end
end


User.user_id = 23423423
User.user_long = -342.34
User.user_lat = 343.3

puts User.user_lat
puts User.user_lat
puts User.user_id
```

Comment: @Mischa i know there is no reason for writing this class. I had this doubt so I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class User
  @user_id = 0
  @user_long = 0
  @user_lat = 0 
  class << self
    attr_accessor :user_id, :user_long, :user_lat
  end
end
```

Comment: @Mischa `class << self` opens up the `self` singleton class so you can define methods on the current `self` object. Its simply another way to write `self.method`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is very much preferred to use instance variables instead of class variables, because of the somewhat strange sharing semantics of class variables:

```
class User
  class << self
    attr_accessor :user_id, :user_long, :user_lat
  end

  self.user_id   = 0
  self.user_long = 0
  self.user_lat  = 0 
end

User.user_id   #=> 0
User.user_long #=> 0
User.user_lat  #=> 0

User.user_id   = 23423423
User.user_long = -342.34
User.user_lat  = 343.3

User.user_id   #=> 23423423
User.user_long #=> -342.34
User.user_lat  #=> 343.3
```

But if you absolutely *must* use class variables, you can simply write your own methods for generating setters and getters. It's not like there's anything magical about `Module#attr_accessor`, it's a method just like any other method:

```
class Module
  def cvar_reader(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_singleton_method(name) { class_variable_get(:"@@#{name}") }
    end
  end

  def cvar_writer(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_singleton_method(:"#{name}=") {|value| class_variable_set(:"@@#{name}", value) }
    end
  end

  def cvar_accessor(*names)
    cvar_reader *names
    cvar_writer *names
  end
end

class User
  cvar_accessor :user_id, :user_long, :user_lat

  self.user_id   = 0
  self.user_long = 0
  self.user_lat  = 0 
end

User.user_id   #=> 0
User.user_long #=> 0
User.user_lat  #=> 0

User.user_id   = 23423423
User.user_long = -342.34
User.user_lat  = 343.3

User.user_id   #=> 23423423
User.user_long #=> -342.34
User.user_lat  #=> 343.3
```

However, it seems like a strange design, regardless of whether you use class instance variables or class variables. Why have a class at all, when you cannot have more than one user in your system anyway? Why not just use an object?

```
class << (User = Object.new)
  attr_accessor :user_id, :user_long, :user_lat
end

User.user_id   = 0
User.user_long = 0
User.user_lat  = 0 

User.user_id   #=> 0
User.user_long #=> 0
User.user_lat  #=> 0

User.user_id   = 23423423
User.user_long = -342.34
User.user_lat  = 343.3

User.user_id   #=> 23423423
User.user_long #=> -342.34
User.user_lat  #=> 343.3
```

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is something like this,

```
class User
  class << self
    attr_accessor :user_id
  end
end
```

Which will create instance variables on the class's [metaclass](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/), rather than class variables. This might give you what you need but I do suggest reading and understanding Ruby's object model.